# RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported for ip xfrm command on debian os

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ipsec

I am trying to configure ipsec through ip xfrm commands in debian image. I am facing operation not supported error. Kindly help me on where am going wrong.

Logs:

```
NE145:2-10*:/tmp # ip xfrm policy add src 10.1.1.1/24 dst 224.0.0.5/32 proto 89 dir out ptype main tmpl src 10.1.1.1 dst 224.0.0.5 proto esp mode transport level required
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

NE145:2-10*:/tmp # uname -a
Linux NE145 4.19.5-rt4+ #5 SMP PREEMPT RT Wed Apr 17 13:37:01 PDT 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
NE145:2-10*:/tmp #
```

config file :

```
CONFIG_XFRM=y
CONFIG_XFRM_ALGO=y
CONFIG_XFRM_USER=y
# CONFIG_XFRM_INTERFACE is not set
# CONFIG_XFRM_SUB_POLICY is not set
# CONFIG_XFRM_MIGRATE is not set
# CONFIG_XFRM_STATISTICS is not set
```

Answer (score 0):

xfrm itself is just the basic framework – you also need to have the individual features loaded:

- The tunnel type:

  - `xfrm4_mode_transport` (CONFIG_INET4_XFRM_MODE_TRANSPORT)
  - `xfrm6_mode_transport` (CONFIG_INET6_XFRM_MODE_TRANSPORT)
- The encapsulation:

  - `esp4` (CONFIG_INET_ESP)
  - `esp6` (CONFIG_INET6_ESP)

For individual states, you'll also need:

- The cipher: `aes`, `aes_x86_64` (CONFIG_CRYPTO_AES, etc.)
- The cipher mode: `cbc`, `ctr`, `gcm` (CONFIG_CRYPTO_CBC, etc.)